Opening Microsoft word file from web Application on Local server
we have an old unsecure web application (http), installed on internal server on the company
the IIS configurations is as following :
1- Web site Authentication :

Annominous authentication Enabled
Forms authentication enabled

2- Website Data authentication:

basic authentication enabled
forms authentication enabled

one of its features is to open reports from server using the Microsoft word installed on the client machines
this feature works fine till office 2013
for client machines that uses oficce 2016 ~ to office 365 the reports are blocked and word opened empty (completely empty not even blank page)
on some client machines get an error message that the file blocked because the source uses a sign in method that may be unsecure
i tried the following :

adding the site to trusted locations in office and Machine internet options
using self-signed certificate on IIS but word give me an error that and  installing it on the client machine to be trusted but gave me the following error :
the name of the security certificate is invalid or does not match the name of the site.
tried to create local certificate using mkcert and openSSl but failed
-- changing the IIS Authentication method to be Annominous but this make the report opens but in readonly mode , can not edit or save it

so sorry for the long question but tried to cover the full scenario
